# Vue js parameter can't get in route

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I use VueJS and laravel but now I can't get parameter value, please help me to solve this problem.

my VueJS code:

```
getTestData:function () {
    let config = {
        params: {
            id: 1
        }
    };
    axios.post('{{ route('get_user_data') }}', config)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            // app.posts=response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {

        })
    },
```

My Controller code:

```
public function testData(Request $request)
{
    // how to get this value?
}
```

My route

```
Route::post('get-user-data','TestController@testData')->name('get_user_data');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a post request to get some values out of database. A get request would be more suitable.

You need to have the param in the route definition

```php
Route::get('get-user-data/{id}','TestController@testData')->name('get_user_data');

//If you want to use post route

Route::post('get-user-data/{id}','TestController@testData')->name('get_user_data');
```

Then in controller method you can get the value out of the request

```php
public function testData(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->route('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> [`params`](https://github.com/axios/axios) are the URL parameters to be sent with the request

You could [retrieve input from query string](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string) in your controller as:

```
public function testData(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->query('id');
}
```